# How to assign correct permissions to both webserver and svn users?

Tags: permissions, webserver, svn

I've an issue with files ownerships.

I have a drupal website and the "files" folder needs to be owned by "www-data" in order to let the users to upload files with php.

However I'm now using svn and I need all folders and files to be own by "svnuser" in order to work.

So now, I guess I need to add both users to a group with proper permissions. I'm not sure what exactly to do, could you tell me what are the exact necessary steps?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also a group called `www-data`. The files you have in your webroot should all belong to that group and have write-right for the group. Assuming your webroot is `/var/www` you can do this by executing (as root or by using `sudo`)

```
chgrp -R www-data /var/www
chmod -R g+rwX /var/www
```

Comment: It seems that the changing the grp is not the solution. It depends on the owner. If the owner is www-data than I cannot commit such files, if the owner is svnuser than I cannot upload files into the folders with php.

Comment: Should I maybe create a group and add both users ? Is this the best solution ?

Comment: The user `www-data` is automatically a member of the group `www-data`. You could add the `svnuser` to that group as well. But if the group has write-permission on the directory (and its subdirectories) the `www-data` user should be able to upload files to that directory.

Comment: I've added svnuser to www-data and the www-data group has all permissions over files, but still it gives me an error. The svnuser is actually my Ubuntu username, so probably svn doesn't use the group instead.

Comment: I've also tried to change owner to svn-data, but then the webserver cannot upload files. This is strange, because the files still are under www-data group which has all permissions (775)

Answer (score 0):

Is this link helpful?
[Geek Thoughts](http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2010/03/shared-folders-in-ubuntu-with-setgid.html)